# Is u_int64_t available on 32-bit machine?

Tags: c, linux

I want to use a `u_int64_t` variable as search key.

Is `u_int64_t` available on 32-bit machine?

If not, do I have to divide this variable into two variables? Then as a search key, it is a bit more troublesome.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An unsigned 64-bit integral type is not guaranteed by the C standard, but is typically available on 32-bit machines, and on virtually all machines running Linux. When present, the type will be named `uint64_t` (note one less underscore) and declared in the `<stdint.h>` header file.

Comment: An at least 64-bit wide unsigned integer is guaranteed to be available under the names `uintleast64_t` (typedef in `<stdint.h>`) and `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @rubenvb: Note that `long long` is *allowed* to be *larger* than 64 bit.

Comment: @DevSolar rubenvb's comment does say "**at least** 64-bits wide". The OP on the other hand most likely wants just a 64-bit type and doesn't care about the rare architectures that might support a wider type without supporting an exactly 64-bit one.

Comment: In this case, `uint_least64_t` is probably what they want: it’s exactly 64 bits wide if such a type exists, and on some unusual architecture with no `uint64_t`, `uint_least64_t` would be the next available size up, so it would still transparently work.

Comment: That said, it’s theoretically possible, I guess, that there might someday be a system where a 64-bit type exists for compatibility, but 72-bit `long long int` words are significantly faster. Albeit extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 5):

Yes 64 bit integer datatype is supported on a 32 bit machine.

In C89 Standard , long long (≥ 64, ≥ size of long) type is supported as a [GNU extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Long-Long.html).
In C99 standard, there is [native support](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Reference_Tables#Table_of_Data_Types) for long long(≥ 64, ≥ size of long) integer.

Comment: Note that `long long` is *allowed* to be *larger* than 64 bit.

Comment: Yeah,you are right long long can be more than 64bits wide(although rare), but thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 0):

as per some of the documentation or reading its not quite clear
[__GLIBC_HAVE_LONG_LONG is the one that defines its presense in 32 bit architecture](http://research.engineering.wustl.edu/~beardj/_usr_include_sys_types_h.html)

aprobable solution for usage could be something similar to below

```
#include <sys/types.h>

#ifdef __GLIBC_HAVE_LONG_LONG

    u_int64_t i;

#endif
```

Oh bythe way this is in linux